# Bad Class with StackOverflowException What is C# doing

Tags: c#, exception, stack-overflow

When I call the constructor, the program gets a StackOverflowException.

```
public class User{
    public User(string email, string pass){
        this.email = email;
        this.pass = pass; 
    }
    public string email{
        get => email;
        set => email = email;
    }
    public string pass{
        get => pass;
        set => pass = pass;
    }
}
```

Process is terminating due to StackOverflowException.

Comment: please don't mark it as duplicate of question without good answer.

Comment: If you just want a simple property then you don't have to implement it. Use this `public string Email { get; set; }`. Also, coding convention is to use uppercase for properties, methods, and classes, and lowercase for fields and variables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes infinite loop

```
this.email = email
```

**How to fix**

```
public class User{
    public string e;
    public string p;
    public User(string email, string pass){
        this.e= email;
        this.p= pass; 
    }
}
```

**With properties**

```
public class User{
     public string e;
     public string p;
     public User(string email, string pass){
     this.e= email;
     this.p= pass; 
     }
     public string Pass{

            get { return this.p; }

            set { this.p= value; }

     }
     public string Email{

            get { return this.e; }

            set { this.e= value; }

     }
 }
```

Comment: Kool so what do the fix look like?

Comment: @kevin see edit.

Comment: So are proprieties just broken then?

Comment: @kevin it's optional . i made it more readable .

Comment: so how would it look with proprieties then? PS thanks very much.

Comment: @kevin see next edit.